# Bitcoin sendfrom do not processing transaction

Tags: php, post, bitcoin

I have very strange problem with sendfrom. To process I am using dynamic vales from form received with $_POST.

```
$myaccount = trim($_POST['myaccount']);
$to_wallet = trim($_POST['to_wallet']);
$wammount = trim($_POST['wammount']);
```

I can echo them and I can clearly see all the data passed from form

Now I am inserting them to

```
$message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($myaccount, $to_wallet, $wammount));
```

What I discovered that all the $myaccount, $to_wallet are correctly passed but $wammount causing problem and code is not executed. I am inserting in form 0.0001 inside the field
"wammount" however once this is hard coded

```
$myaccount = trim($_POST['myaccount']);
$to_wallet = trim($_POST['to_wallet']);
$wammount = 0.0001;
```

and running command below everything run well and transaction is processed. Any idea why ?

```
$message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($myaccount, $to_wallet, $wammount));
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($wammount)` show?

Comment: It does show: string(6) "0.0001"

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't be a string?  Maybe it should be a number?  `floatval($wammount);`

Comment: How did you "discover" that `$wammount` is "causing [a] problem"?  Do you see any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does adding `floatval()` do?

```
$wammount = floatval(trim($_POST['wammount']));
```